# Simplification of rational function

Tags: rational-numbers, partial-fractions, rational-functions, rationalising-denominator

I saw the following simplification done:

$$\frac{100}{\frac{900sL}{900+sL}+100}$$
is equal to
$$\frac{sL + 900}{10sL + 900}$$
and was wondering how this is done?

Thank you

Comment: Is this a transfer function from analog signal processing?

Comment: haha yeah, I have a final tomorrow and we were given practice tests and this was one of the solutions with no explanation

Comment: I honestly never liked the material of this course mainly due to my professor not knowing how to explain these stuffs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simple algebraic transformations
$$
\frac{100}{\frac{900sL}{900+sL}+100}=\frac{100}{\frac{900sL}{900+sL}+\frac{100\left( 900+sL \right)}{900+sL}}\\=\frac{100}{\frac{1000sL+90000}{900+sL}}=100\times \frac{900+sL}{1000sL+90000}=\frac{sL+900}{10sL+900}
$$

Comment: i would prefer for the OP to do at least *some* work on his problem

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by first dividing numerator and denominator by $100$ to get $\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{9sL}{900+sL}+1}$

and then multiplying numerator and denominator by $900+sL$ to get $\dfrac{900+sL}{9sL+900+sL}.$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes, thank you for this!